# Bootstrap Search Form in Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a dropdown in my menu but when I click on the search form field inside the dropdown the dropdown instantly closes.

This is my code:

```
 <button id="sharebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown"
            data-close-others="true"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search
    </button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu extended notification">


        <li>
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo $this->Form->create('Search', array('controller' => 'searches', 'action' => 'prodsearch')); ?>


                <div class="input-group">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('newsearchterm', array('required' => true, 'class' => 'form-control', 'label' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Search Products...', 'name' => 'newsearchterm')); ?>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">

                                            <?php
                                            echo $this->Form->button(
                                                '<i class="fa fa-search"></i>',
                                                array(
                                                    'type' => 'submit',
                                                    'class' => 'btn blue',
                                                ),
                                                array('escape' => 'false')
                                            );
                                            ?>


                                        </span>
                </div>


            </div>

            <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>


        </li>


    </ul>
```

(I am using CakePHP which is why the form code is a bit funny)

Answer (score 2):

Add `stopPropagation()` to the your search form field.

```
jQuery('.your-form-selector').click(function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Everything else will work as expected.

[JQuery reference](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

I was just looking for the same thing and found it at [here](http://mifsud.me/adding-dropdown-login-form-bootstraps-navbar/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "li" tags and try. Like this:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo $this->Form->create('Search', array('controller' => 'searches', 'action' => 'prodsearch')); ?>


            <div class="input-group">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('newsearchterm', array('required' => true, 'class' => 'form-control', 'label' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Search Products...', 'name' => 'newsearchterm')); ?>
                <span class="input-group-btn">

                                        <?php
                                        echo $this->Form->button(
                                            '<i class="fa fa-search"></i>',
                                            array(
                                                'type' => 'submit',
                                                'class' => 'btn blue',
                                            ),
                                            array('escape' => 'false')
                                        );
                                        ?>


                                    </span>
            </div>


        </div>

        <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>


   </ul>
```

This worked for me once in adding forms in Bootstrap nav dropdowns.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, I tried this but it still does exactly the same. Even If I just put a P or something as soon as I click on any content it closes.